# Angularjs show only clicked event field instead of showing multiple ng-show values on each click

Tags: angularjs

I want to show only clicked event field, but it was showing multiple views on each click event.

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
  
    $scope.fieldCollectionSingle = [];
    $scope.selectSingle = function (fieldkey, field) {
        $scope.showSingle_Fieldsettings = true;
    };

    $scope.showSingle = function (fieldkey, field, index) {
        return angular.equals(shownSingle, field, index);
    };
    
    $scope.removeName = function (fieldkey) {
        $scope.fieldCollectionSingle.splice(fieldkey, 1);
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">

                   <button class="form-control" ng-click="fieldCollectionSingle.push([])">Single Line Text</button><br/>
         <fieldset ng-click="selectSingle()" class="ui-state-default" ng-repeat="(fieldkey, field) in 

fieldCollectionSingle">
                        <label>{{field.single}}</label> 
                        <input type="text" id = "abc{{fieldkey}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
                      
                        <button class="remove" ng-click="removeName($fieldkey)">-</button>
                    </fieldset>
         
        <div ng-repeat="(fieldkey, field) in fieldCollectionSingle" class="form-group"  ng-show="showSingle_Fieldsettings">
                        <label>Field Label(?)</label><br/>    
                        <fieldset>
                            <input ng-model="field.single" ng-click="setLabel(fieldkey)"  class="fieldLabel">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/vijjusena/17cc74g0/2/ [this is mycode jsfiddle]

Comment: Why are you mixing Angular and jQuery?

Comment: i didn't got exact solution in angularjs, so tried to solve with jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At-last I understood your requirement and edited you JSFiddle to create exactly what you wanted. I have changed few things, but I hope you can understand all of them. If something gets you stuck, ask me.

**Important:** You will have to click on "Default title" text to show the other form to change/update the title.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_vijaydev/17cc74g0/6/). Good luck, have fun!

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <button class="form-control" ng-click="addNewField()">Single Line Text</button>

        <fieldset class="ui-state-default" ng-repeat="(fieldkey, field) in fieldCollectionSingle">
            <label ng-click="selectSingle(field)">{{ field.label }} : </label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="field.value" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
            <button class="remove" ng-click="removeName($fieldkey)">-</button>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group" ng-show="showSingle_Fieldsettings">
            <label>Field Label(?)</label>
            <fieldset>
                <input ng-model="selectedField.label" class="fieldLabel">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much Mr.Vijay .. i'm struggling about this issue from 1wk, u given me great and exact solution to me ... thanx alot

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/sZpkYA0nLSMLUKhJkogi?p=preview hi Vijay Dev, i need ur help, u given me great answer to my previous question, can u pls help me once again in a doubt which i have updated in plunkr .. i want to change label name each together from field label.. pls help me